# Merge 2 css files with duplicate selectors/properties server side?

Tags: css

I'm looking into if it's possible to merge 2 css files into one on the server side in some way?

Let's say there is a "base.css" file on the server that contains the site css, I have full control over this file. Then if a "my.css" file is added to the server, which I have no control over, the 2 files would get merged into one, handling duplicate selectors and merge properties. The "my.css" file should have the highest hierarchy between the two.

In example, the "base.css" looks like this:

```
.foo {
    color: red;
    display: flex;
}

.bar {
    flex-basis: 300px;
}
```

The "my.css" file looks like below. It would also be nice if there was a way of "removing" properties from the "base.css" by declaring this in the "my.css" file so that the merged file would skip this property for the specific selector, something like this:

```
.foo {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.bar {
    background-color: black;
    /*flex-basis: 300px;*/
}
```

The merged file would then look like this:

```
.foo {
    color: green;
    display: flex;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.bar {
    background-color: black;
}
```

The reason I'm asking is because right now we serve the "base.css" but user are able to add there own "my.css" file to the server in order to make changes to the design and layout by overriding the "base.css" file. This will result in one more request and also a lot of duplicate selectors trying to "work against" our initial "base.css".

So I'm curious if there is a way of doing this?

Comment: I think you'll need to add some more details about your server-side if you want any specific answers, but given how CSS works, the quick and dirty solution is: Append the contents of `my.css` to the end of `base.css` and return that combined file.

Comment: You could serve both CSS files, as one file, by simply appending the `my.css` at the end of the `base.css`. That would solve one of your problems.

Comment: you can not just merge 2 CSS files and think that it works flawlessly. It also is completely unnecessary. For once you have to look at specificity weight! Also, the whole reason to have 2 separate files is so that the user CSS can overwrite the base CSS when needed but still maintain the integrity of the base CSS for others. When serving 2 files you outsource the needed computing power to the user's device. This ultimately allows for asynchronous downloading as well as lowering required server computing power.

Comment: @tacoshy, Sure, I get that serving the two separate files maintains the integrity of the base css. But in my case the integrity of the base css is not a priority if a user adds their own css in order to alter the base css. Then the priority changes. The integrity, priority and whether it's necessary or not is really not a part of the question. The question is if this is doable in a reasonable way.

Comment: Yes, appending the my.css file to the base.css would solve the request part. That's certainly something I plan to do as a minimum, just curious if there would be someway of doing a "proper" merge between the two in a reasonable way.

Comment: Be aware that if you want to perfectly merge the CSS rules yourself, you will eventually have to implement all used CSS selectors and on top take [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) into consideration. Other selectors "working against" your base CSS is absolutely intended by CSS. If you want certain things from your base CSS preserved have a third CSS that overrides the user CSS with !important - users can however always choose a more specific selector. That could be difficult to resolve.